# Wordpress multisite, domain mapping www issue

Tags: wordpress

Hey there, I have installed wordpress multisite and domain mapping plugin.

The problem is with the www...if i setup the multisite without www and i access the site without www everything works fine
But if i access it without www, it reddirects to the main site.
Any ideea why?
Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-mu-domain-mapping-add-an-www-prefix?replies=7

Edit:
Actually, I found a non-coding easier solution. In the 'Super Admins -> Domains' page, add both the www. and non-www. versions of the domain, but select the box of 'primary' for if you want to mainly use for www. or non-www. and both will be assigned to the blog.

Comment: I did that to :), tho was not sure if it was a good option, was afraid there might be something screwy with it;)

Comment: By the way, I'm using wp hive for now, much simpler and i think effective. My only worry is I'm not sure that plugin will be supported in the future

Answer (score 5):

This is the setup that has worked for me:

- Go to /wp-admin/network -> Settings -> Domain mapping:

  - Set your primary site domain (**without www**) on Server CNAME domain, leave IP empty
  - **Uncheck** remote login
  - **check** permanent redirect
  - **check** user domain mapping page
  - **uncheck** Redirect administration pages to site's original domain
  - **uncheck** Disable primary domain check
- Go to /wp-admin/network/ -> setting -> Domains: Map each site to its domain (**without www**)

**For each site that you want to default to www** (except the primary)

- Go /wp-admin/ -> Tools -> domain mapping

  - In **Add new domain** insert the site's domain (**with www**)
  - **Check** Primary domain for this blog

(Please note that you have to make sure beforehand that your domain is working with and without www)

Comment: This is how you do it. Don't need to add any htaccess rule.
Great answer @NiloVelez