# Wordpress MultiSite on Windows Azure - domain with www

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns

I'm sorry, but I am confused, so I thought to ask my question here.

I have a Windows Azure Reserved Website instance, and added a domain through Managed Domains.
To get the domain added I had to add this in  my DNS:

> awverify CNAME awverify..azurewebsites.net.

I added the domain in  my Wordpress MultiSite setup as follows:
domainname: http://domainname.com using subdirectories.

To this point everything works perfect, I can access the domain on **domain.com** without the **www** prefix.

With typing this question, I found also this topic [Wordpress multisite, domain mapping www issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411088/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping-www-issue)

I installed MU, and followed everything. The mapping works, the **domain.com** maps to **www.domain.com** but I get again the Azure Server Error:

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Are my DNS settings wrong, or is this Wordpress or Azure specific?

Comment: I think it is a Azure specific problem, because of the 404 page returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added a cname record for "www.yourdomain.com" ? I have not used Azure, or I would provide a more complete answer, but it sounds like you just defined the DNS entry for yourdomain.com .  You also need to create a CNAME for "www.yourdomain.com"

edit: Also, if you type "ping yourdomain.com" into the command prompt, does it show the same IP as "ping www.yourdomain.com" ?  If you provide the actual domain it would be easier to troubleshoot as well.